# sort results with method defined in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a users table and a contracts table and there relationship is as below:

user.rb

```
has_many :contracts

def current_year_contracts
 total = 0
 contracts.where('entry_date >= ?', Date.current.beginning_of_year).each do |entry|
   total += entry.total_number.to_f
 end
 total
end
```

contract.rb

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

The issue I am facing here is how to use current_year_contracts to sort users in ascending or descending order.

```
@users = User.all.order(users.current_year_contracts "#{direction}")
```

direction is the can be ascending or descending.

Comment: What results are you getting when you use the code above?

Answer (score 0):

If sorting in Ruby is OK, you can run this code:

```rb
@users = User.all.sort{|a,b| a.current_year_contracts <=> b.current_year_contracts}
```

If you require SQL sorting we need to know what database server is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
@users = User.joins(:contracts)
         .where('contracts.entry_date >= ?', Date.current.beginning_of_year)
         .group('users.id')
         .order('SUM(contracts.total_number) DESC')
```

to make it much more reusable

you can create a scope and move the logic there what you can do is

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :order_by_current_year_contracts, -> do
    joins(:contracts)
    .where('contracts.entry_date >= ?', Date.current.beginning_of_year)
    .group('users.id')
    .order('SUM(contracts.total_number) DESC')
  end
end
```

and just use `User.order_by_current_year_contracts`
WOAH!!!!

But what if I want to get the list in ASC order? 
I've got you `User.order_by_current_year_contracts.reverse_order`

P.s: You need to modify your `current_year` logic in the query if you really want just current year contracts to be retrieved. Again, that depends upon your logic but I've given you what you asked for. So my job here is done. ✅

Happy learning and vote up to this solution if you like it!

Answer (score 0):

```
User.joins(:contracts)
    .group(:id)
    .where(contracts: { entry_date: ..Date.current.beginning_of_year })
    .order([Contract.arel_table[:total_number].sum, :desc])
```

`..Date.current.beginning_of_year` is a beginless range which ActiveRecord translates into GTE (`>=`). You can do LTE and LT by using endless ranges.

If you want to have the sum in the result you can move it into the select clause instead:

```
User.joins(:contracts)
    .select(
      User.arel_table[Arel.star], 
      Contract.arel_table[:total_number].sum.as('total_number_of_contacts')
    )
    .group(:id)
    .where(contracts: { entry_date: ..Date.current.beginning_of_year })
    .order(total_number_of_contacts: :desc)
```

Comment: As a tiny side note the last part might not work on Oracle and you might have to repeat the aggregation in the order clause there. But then again who uses Rails and Oracle together?